# Lattice-based cryptography prone to side channel attack?

Tags: lattice-crypto, side-channel-attack

Is lattice-based cryptography still prone to side channel attacks? What are some mitigation strategies, if any?

Comment: You'd probably have to specify at least which type of scheme so that you can know what operations it uses, so that you can know whether or not implementations of those operations are prone to side channel attacks (which target the implementation and not the algorithm).

Comment: You'd also probably need to specify which side channels as well (timing, cache, DPA, EMI, Fault)

Comment: Is there any cryptography not prone to side channel attacks?

Answer (score -1):

my understanding is that Supersingular isogeny Diffie-Hellman (SIDH) is fully protected against timing and cache attacks as all operations on secret data run in constant time. That was my own experience.

Comment: Please note that SIDH usually _does not_ fall under "lattice-based" schemes. So technically you have answered a different question.